# Can removing final from a class definition break backwards compatibility?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, backwards-compatibility, final

I'm currently reading Effective Java by Joshua Bloch and Item 17 is 'Design and document for  inheritance or else prohibit it'. The author suggest to prohibit inheritance by default.

Is it safe to declare classes final by default and in a later release remove the final keyword if there is a need to extend the class? Will it break backwards compatibility against code that was compiled with a previous version?

If so it appears that it is a safer bet to make all classes final and only remove it in a future release if there is a well supported demand.

Comment: It somewhat depends on how much of a living, breathing API you have.  If you make changes and releases all the time, it's not so bad to wait a week to get the ability to inherit.  If, on the other hand, Java did that with their base JDK classes by default, it would bring programmers to tears to have to wait 5 years for the "fix".

Comment: @Kirk Woll if it takes 5 years to change from final to non-final, how long should it take to change from non-final to final?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It breaks neither binary nor source compatibility. That's one of the reasons it's a good idea to make classes final; it's always OK to change your mind about it.

**[The Java Language Specification, §13.4.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/binaryComp.html#44987)**, has the following to say about binary compatibility:

> Changing a class that was declared `final` to no longer be declared `final` does not break compatibility with pre-existing binaries.

I suppose you still *could* make up a construed example where it actually could break a program; like bytecode-generating a class inheriting from the supposedly `final` class, and then loading that generated class and relying on getting a `VerifyError`.

Answer (score 2):

My thoughts on this:

Removing the `final` on a class won't cause immediate problems. But consider this:

There was a final class called AdamsFactory which you change to non-final. Two months from now, a new programmer called Dilbert joins your team.
He subclasses your used-to-be-final class into ScottFactory, but breaks the Liskov's Substitutability Principle.

Then he has your ComicStripPrinter class use ScottFactory instead of AdamsFactory. Something is bound to break.

Which brings us back to what Joshua Block says:

If you intend inheritance: design it with deliberation, and document it. If you do not intend inheritance, then prevent it.

I hope what I said was not a big load-a-crap.

---

EDIT:

Go the the [preface of Java Langauge Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/j.preface3.html), and search for Joshua Bloch :)

Comment: The person who designed AdamsFactory did not know whether to make it final/non-final, so PHB mandated it be non-final (by default).  Later Dilbert makes a compelling case for AdamsFactory to be final, but by this time there are about one trillion classes extending AdamsFactory some breaking Liskov's Principle.  If Dilbert makes the change all those classes are broken.  Everone hates Dilbert.

Answer (score 2):

If you are designing something like Java Standard API, that millions of programmers will use for many years, yes, think like Joshua Bloch. FORWARD EVOLUTION is crucial.

99% of Java programs are not. They are developed for internal use, the impact of API change is tiny, usually all source code are available for refactoring. SIMPLICITY is key for such programs. If you have complex and fancy designs, or you spend all your time thinking about final or not, you are wasting time.

I blame Joshua for not setting proper disclaimers for his suggestions.

Comment: Well, YAGNI is all fine and dandy, but changing your IDE Java class template to declare all classes as `final` is a one time thing to do, and sensible class design always makes long and medium term maintenance easier (often but not always, it helps even in short term), and navigating to a class declaration and removing `final` is a very easy thing to do, if you feel you should need it.

Comment: while you are at it, make all fields and methods final too.